# How to verify that a complex equation only has real solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers

As an example, let's examine

$$(4-2i)z + 8 = 4+2i$$

If we solve this like a regular ol' equation, we get $z = -1$, but it's somewhat normal for complex equations solved like this to have "hidden" complex solutions, leaving me with just the real subset of solutions.

Is there a way to verify that $z = -1$ is the only solution, visually or otherwise?

Comment: $z=-1$ is not a solution, because $-4+2i+8\neq 4-2i$.

Comment: "*If we solve this like a regular ol' equation*"... "*is there a way to verify*"  What you did *was* such a verification.  The complex numbers form a field.  That means that cancellation laws apply just as they do in the field of real numbers.  Subtracting eight from both sides and then dividing both sides by $4-2i$ is exactly what you'd do to solve for $z$ exactly with nothing missing.  That said, are you certain you performed your arithmetic correctly?

Comment: @DietrichBurde - Sorry, $\pm$ error on the RHS. Fixed.

Comment: @JMoravitz - So it's really only in the cases where we do things like divide by an expression containing the variable, or take roots of such expressions that we should worry about dropping solutions, like with real-valued variables?

Comment: You shouldn't ever divide by an expression that could equal zero.  In $z^2=iz$ for instance the *proper* way to do this is to rearrange as $z^2-iz=0$ and factor as $z(z-i)=0$ which implies that one of those terms in the product was zero, i.e. that $z=0$ or $z=i$.  Could you have worded it as "assume $z\neq 0$, then we can divide both sides by $z$ to go from $z^2=iz$ to $z=i$, and then assume otherwise after"?  Yes, but it is poor form.  As for taking roots and such, yes.  One should always be wary when trying to perform an operation that is not uniquely reversible.

Answer (score 1):

One might also treat the equation $ \ (4-2i)·z + 8 \ = \  4+2i \ $ in this way.  If we designate $ \ w \ = \ 4 + 2i \ \ , \ $ the equation can be expressed as
$$ \overline{w} · z \ + \ 2·\mathfrak{Re}(w) \ \ = \ \ w \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \overline{w} · z \ + \  (w \ + \ \overline{w}) \ \ = \ \ w \ \ \Rightarrow \ \   (z \ + \ 1) ·     \overline{w}  \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

Since $ \ \overline{w} \ \neq \ 0 \ , \ $ the only solution of the equation is $ \ z \ = \ -1 \ \ . \ $

A vectorial representation in the Argand plane would be along the lines of

[image]

Since the complex numbers "carry over" the rules of "standard" real arithmetic, we need not be concerned that complex linear equations could  have more than one root.  Similarly, the vectorial representation would only be realized for *one* particular complex multiplier (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

If we set $z=a+ib$ then we have that,
$$(4-2i)(a+ib)+8=4-2i$$
$$4a+i(-2a+4b)+2b=4-2i$$
So finally we have that,
$$4a+2b=4$$
$$4b-2a=-2$$
Solve them and your proof is done